# Java regular expression: avoiding logical operator

Tags: java, regex

The following regular expression creates a StackOverflowError when applied on a large html page:

```
<li.*?>(.|\s)*?</li>
```

My hypothesis is that it is due to the logical "OR" operator (`|`) that creates recursive calls in the matcher and, due to the large html page size that needs to be parsed, it creates the stack overflow.

Is there any way I can rewrite this regular expression without the "OR " operator (knowing that I want to capture content that is potentially split over multiple lines, hence the need of `\s`)?

Many thanks,
Tom

Comment: Any reason why you are not using proper HTML/XML parser?

Comment: [tag:jsoup] is your friend.

Comment: I'm not using a proper HTML parser because input HTML is not well formed

Comment: @Tom Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Actually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg is a more cogent explanation of the problem.

Comment: For example, you could have an html string that looks like this: `<li data-ex=">bwahaha</li>"></li>`.  It's perfectly valid html, and a regex parser is going to have a miserable time with that.

Comment: Use this `<(?:(?:/?\w+\s*/?)|(?:\w+\s+(?:(?:(?:"[\S\s]*?")|(?:'[\S\s]*?'))|(?:[^>]*?))+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>`

Comment: `(.|\s)` = `[\S\s]` = `(?s).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses `DOT_ALL, (?:s)` to let the dot `.` also match line break characters.

```
(?s)<li[^>]*>.*?</li>
```

Important however is that no back throw to the `<li...>` occurs, hence the variation I chose.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on a simple example (<li>foor bar</li>) split on 3 lines but the DOT_ALL solved it for my initial regexp. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I had an extraneous colon; which I corrected now.